# TFS 2017 permissions issue

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I migrated our old TFS 2010 server to a new TFS 2017 last week.
Everything seemed to be working fine.
Until someone asked to start a stopped collection he needed to work on.
I added him to the Collection administrator group, but we he goes to Visual Studio 2015, he can't see the team projects.
When he uses the web interface, he can see the projects but still can't do everything. (can't add users to a group in a project)

Even I as a TFS Server admin, can't add users to a specific group in a projects.
Has somebody seen this behavior before? I thought that the collection admins have full control over de projects in a collection.
Does VS2015 need a update/patch in order to work properly with TFS 2017?

Comment: The user is likely not in the correct Access Level. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/change-access-levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **known issue/bug** in TFS2017 and will be fixed in TFS2017 update1.

> We have fixed the problem and the bug fix will be included in TFS 2017
>   Update 1. Thank you for helping us build a better Visual Studio!
>
> *Visual Studio Team ♦♦ · 01/19 14:25*

Either to update your TFS2017 to update1 or you can use the command-line `TFSSecurity.exe` to assign permission as a workaround. This utility succeeds even if the WebUI fails.
Below's how to do it:

> 1. Add the username you use on your computer to the Project Collection
>      Administrator group.
> 2. Open command or PowerShell prompt in your Visual Studio 2015 folder,
>      e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>              14.0\Common7\IDE.
> 3. Run `TFSSecurity.exe /g+ "[Project-Name]\Project Administrators" n:"Username to make Project Admin" /collection:CollectionURL`.

More details about this bug, please refer this similar question: [Permission problems since upgrading to TFS 2017](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/10661/permission-problems-since-upgrading-to-tfs-2017.html)

Comment: I have installed Update 1 RC 2. But it only solved half of the problem. I can now add rights as a server admin. But in some cases, a project collection admin still can't see all the projects.

Comment: @MatrixCow When did you add the project collection admin permission for a user? Before the update or after the update? Try to add the permission after the update. Also  give a try with **using the command** instead of web UI.

Comment: As a workaround we added the project administrators group to the projet administrators group. And now it seems to be working. Thanks for the help